# Ansible to run playbooks from github

Tags: ansible

I manage MapR based large scale infrastructure running on on prem dc's. As part of configuration management enhancement we have written several of playbooks and keeping everything in github. Now I dont want anyone to download/clone those repo local to Ansible client nodes and run it from there. Is there a way where i can run playbooks from ansible without downloading to local machine. So basically what i want, a script/playbook where i pass which playbook to run, it should download that playbook and run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for some web interface that users will simply run your tasks, and in the background it will execute Ansible.

There are many methods to achieve what you need, however most likely you're looking for any of this:

[AWX project](https://github.com/ansible/awx) - official ansible web interface

[Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) or [Rundeck](https://www.rundeck.com/open-source) - more bloated software that you can create your own "jobs" for users to interact with, create CI/CD flows and cron tasks to run any time you need.

You can also look into workflow automation, such as [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/)

There are alternatives to all the mentions I put, so be sure to check everything when deciding what you need.

Comment: Does AWX support Ansible's standalone installation ? I dont have Ansible tower setup in my environment. However I will give a try to AWX also.

Comment: Other thing is, Yes I want to keep ansible pulling playbooks from git and running totally in background. There is existing challenge in my environment is none of the admin follow the configuration management guideline and we are running into big risk with each servers running in different configuration. So the whole idea is not to maintain any local copy of ansible. Process/Playbook/UI should run the playbook directly from git and delete local copy